# Sumar total de ventas por dia - PHP

Tags: php7

Estoy haciendo un sistema el cual me permite ver las ventas del día, pero al sumarlas no me esta mostrando el resultado total, es decir: `día 1 -> ($1 + $1)` en total daría `$2` pero solo me esta mostrando el numero `$1`.

Este es el query que estoy utilizando

```
SELECT fecha, sum(total) total FROM ventas GROUP BY DAY(fecha)
```

el campo `total` es el que contiene el precio para sumar los valores.

Y ¿como podría obtener el total de las ventas del día anterior?

Comment: @masterguru ahi señalo 1+1 = 2 solo que lo separe por comas y es solo las ventas del dia actual

Comment: Quizas esto lo solucione:  `SELECT fecha, sum(total) as total FROM ventas GROUP BY DAY(fecha)`  (creo que te falta el `as`)

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es tu columna `fecha`? ¿Qué significa para ti sumar **por días**: **por días** de la semana (lunes, martes, miércoles...), **por días** del mes sin importar el año, **por días** del mes y del año, **por días** del año? Convendría también que muestres un pequeño set de datos y un ejemplo concreto, con un valor dado, según el cual te arroja el valor que dices en tu pregunta. Dinos también qué SGBD estás usando: MySQL, SQL Server, Postgresql, Oracle, etc. (lo puedes poner como etiqueta en la pregunta). Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: @masterguru el `AS` se puede omitir.

Comment: @A.Cedano No lo sabia, ya veo, gracias por la info, no tenia ni idea de eso, la verdad

Comment: @masterguru aunque el que *se pueda* no significa que *se deba* hacer. Hay que guardar las buenas costumbres y si se usa el código queda más claro y más conforme al estándar SQL.

Comment: @A.Cedano Sí, sí, claro, particularmente me gusta mas con el `AS`, lo leo mejor y no pensaba cambiarlo.  Ya me parecía raro que la consulta no le diera error.

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos resolvieron muy bien mi duda, como podria sacar las ventas del día anterior?